# Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis Theorem $1.20 (a)$

Tags: real-analysis

> $1.20 (a)$: If $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \gt 0$, then there is a positive integer n such that $nx \gt y$.

The proof in the book:

> Let $A$ be the set of all $nx$, where $n$ runs through the positive integers. If (a) were false, then $y$ would be an upper bound of $A$. But then $A$ has a least upper bound in $R$. Put $\alpha = \sup A$. Since $x \gt 0$, $\alpha -x \lt \alpha$, and $\alpha -x$ is not an upper bound of $A$. Hence $\alpha -x \lt mx$ for some positive integer $m$. But then $\alpha \lt (m+1)x \in A$, which is impossible, since $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $A$. $\blacksquare$

My question: for $A$ to have an upper bound in $R$ it also has to be non-empty. The author doesn't say that anywhere in the proof. Why? The proof must be incomplete, right?

Comment: Well $x\in A$ so it is non-empty.

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: @RUBENGONÇALOMOROUÇO No need to delete the question, it is a legitimate query. Your question could help others who also have the same question and find this post. Do consider upvoting and accepting an answer if you find it helpful, though.

Comment: In general, Rudin doesn't spell out every detail in his proofs, expecting the reader to fill in anything that's missing. This is a mild example; he leaves more details to the reader in later chapters. This is not out of laziness on Rudin's part; he   wants the reader to be actively engaged in order to learn more effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear from the context that $A$ is non empty, since $A=\{nx: n \in \Bbb N\}$, so atleast your $x=1 \cdot x \in A$