# Walter Rudin Theorem 1.20 (a) Proof

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Theorem 1.20

(a) If $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x > 0$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that  $nx > y$.

In the proof, set $A$ is assumed to have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$ that implies set $A$ is bounded above.

But I don't known how set $A$ is bounded above, given the constraint, $x$ is a positive real number and $n$ is a natural number.

More clarification:

$$A = \{nx\in\mathbb{R}_{>0} \mid (n\in\mathbb{N})\wedge(x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})\}$$

My question is: how this set $A$ have a upper bound?

And the whole theorem and proof didn't really make sense to me.

I mean, if this theorem were reversed, i.e. $nx < y$, I wouldn't be able to make difference between these two scenario.

Potential duplicate post: is referring to possibility of set A being empty. In this post, I’m asking(implicitly) about contradiction statement of theorem and bdd property of set. Non empty set is just one of the condition must satisfy to talk about bddness of sets.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Questions are expected to be fully self-contained: they must define any problem they reference. Also, they must include any attempts at solving the problem, as well as the particular part of the problem that help is needed in.

Comment: Hi user. You can copy the statement of the theorem from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476689

Comment: `\in` creates $\in$

Comment: I marked up the question with mathjax but it didn't go through...

Comment: "In the proof, set A is assumed to have a least upper bound in R" No, the proof does not assume this.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3284246/9003

Comment: The proof, supposes towards a contradiction, that there is an upper bound, and it turns out to be impossible.

Comment: How do you think that post answer my question?

Comment: @Adam Rudinson Then what proof assume ?

Comment: Rudin is assuming the negation of "There is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $nx\gt y$" by  assuming "For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $nx\le y$", which is essentially saying $A=\{nx:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ has an upper bound of $y$. Then, presumably, a contradiction is reached.

Comment: @robjohn can you please write that text in layman language?

Comment: Although this question asks about the same Theorem in Rudin's book as the cited duplicate, the question seems to be about a different aspect of the proof of that Theorem.

Comment: @user264745: $\in$ means "in", $\mathbb{N}$ is the natural numbers, which is the positive integers. $A=\{nx:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ says that $A$ is the set of all $nx$ where $n$ is a natural number. Rudin is assuming the logical opposite of what he wants to prove and shows that that leads to a contradiction. That is called an indirect proof, or proof by contradiction.

Comment: @robjohn I don't understand this kind of statement $A/matbbb.....$. by layman language I mean to say, write set A instead of $A$

Comment: @user264745: is your browser not rendering the latex properly? I don't see anything that looks like what you typed.

Comment: @robjohn yes perhaps that is the case

Comment: @user264745: Does [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4DAk.png) look better?

Comment: @robjohn yup, but it doesn't help much. You basically, rephrased second line of proof.

Comment: I started writing an answer, but there is too much to write in response to OP so I gave up. I would recommend OP trying to prove that, if (a) is false, then $y$ would be an upper bound of $A$, by using the *definition of upper bound* from earlier in the chapter. And then try to think why there wouldn't be an analogous proof if you replaced $nx>y$ with $nx<y$.

Comment: Fisrt of all i dont understand why are you taking everthing for granted. How does this statement " if (a) is false ...... y would be upper bound of set A" make sense to you ? According to you, How set A is finite (bounded)? I think, you don't "really" understand the question .

Comment: @user264745: if you are reading a book about real analysis, then it seemed reasonable to assume that you had encountered a level of logic which included proof by contradiction. First of all a set of real numbers can be bounded without being finite. If you are having problems with these concepts, perhaps it would be better to ask a more basic question, rather than have the concepts needed for this proof getting mixed up with the more basic concepts.

Comment: Rudin is trying to prove the conclusion "there is a positive integer $n$ such that $nx\gt y$", so a common method of proof is to assume the negation (logical opposite) of that conclusion and derive a contradiction. The fact that the negation of the conclusion implies a contradiction says that the conclusion is true. the logical negation of "there is a positive integer $n$ such that $nx\gt y$" is "for any positive integer $n$, $nx\le y$".

Comment: @robjohn "A bounded set of real no. can be bounded without being finite" what do you mean by that. Ok forget everything, let nx = +infinity (that's how set A is defined) then y must be greater than infinity.

Comment: A set being bounded means that there is a real number that is greater than all of the elements of the set. A set being finite means that there is a finite number of elements in the set. +infinity is not a real number.

Comment: By saying infinity I mean if you chose a particular no. in set A we can add one to that no. to make it more bigger.

Comment: An example: $[0,1]$ is an infinite set of real numbers that is bounded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124776/discussion-between-robjohn-and-user264745).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think I have spotted a potential area of confusion.

I think throughout the proof, it may help to imagine $x$ as a fixed positive real number, so let $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

With this in mind, let's amend your definition of the set $A$ (because the one you gave lets $x$ vary as well- which is confusing). Let

$$A = \{nx\in\mathbb{R}_{>0} \mid (n\in\mathbb{N})\}.$$

The statement,

> (a) is false

means that,

If $y\in\mathbb{R}$ , then **there is no** positive integer $n$ such that  $nx > y$,

i.e.

If $y\in\mathbb{R}$ then **for all** positive integers $n,$ we have $nx \leq y$,

which is the same as saying,

The set $A$ is bounded above by $y$.

Now go back and see if the above logic works whenever $x$ is replaced by a positive real number. I think it does.

If you agree, then surely you agree that "(a) is false" implies that "the set $A$ is bounded above by $y$".

Note that this only gets us to sentence 2 of the proof, although hopefully it helped clear up some things. If not, then oh well, I'll let the next guy try...

But if you do agree with this, then you should continue on with the proof after sentence 2.

$$$$

Edit (copying from my comments below):

It is easy to assert that "the set $A$ is ("obviously") not bounded above" without proof. However, actually proving it is not so easy, and this is because writing proofs isn't easy. Saying "Set $A$ is not bounded from above because $n$ is a natural number" isn't a convincing argument, because this more-or-less assumes that Theorem 1.20(a) is clearly true here: but you're not allowed to use the theorem you're trying to prove when trying to prove that theorem.

If you think that Set $A$ is not bounded above, you need to provide a convincing argument. And this is exactly what Rudin does with his proof: he provides a convincing logical argument that Set $A$ is not bounded above. He does this by assuming (a) is false, and then $y$ would be an upper bound of $A$ by definition. He then shows that an absurdity arises, and therefore, (a) is true (argument by contradiction).

Note that it is clear from the outset that "the set $A$ is bounded above" is equivalent to saying" (a) is false". And saying "the set $A$ is not bounded above" is equivalent to saying "(a) is true".

However, it *isn't* immediately obvious whether or not $A$ is actually bounded above or not (this is more or less what we are trying to prove - and Rudin proves that, in fact, $A$ is not bounded above). It might *seem obvious to you* that Theorem 1.20 is true, but in order to show that it is true you need to, well, prove that it is true.

Comment: For you, transition from negating the theorem statement to conclusion (y is an upper bound of set A) is quiet obvious. But here is the thing, the way we define set A, generic way, implies A = (0, infinity) open interval from zero to infinity. So, after negating the statement it really doesn't make sense to say element y is greater than or equal to all the elements of set A because of the way we define set A. When you say y is an upper bound of A. The same moment you'r contradicting your own definition of set A.

Comment: What if we define set A after negating thm's statement. In a sense, negatation of the theorem implies y is an upper bound of set A. But is it legit to define a quantity(set A) which contradict the contradiction statement(y > or = nx)?

Comment: Please can you explain why you think *my* definition of $A$ implies that $A = (0,\infty)\ $?

Comment: Well, it's self defined. nx € +ve real no.

Comment: No, that’s not what my definition of $A$ is. My definition *fixes* (i.e. chooses a) positive real $x>0$ first, and then the defines the set $A = \{ x, 2x, 3x, 4x, \ldots \}$.

Comment: The fact that even after fixing the value of x. Set A is not bdd from above because n € natural no.

Comment: Firstly, $(0,\infty)\ $ is all the real numbers greater than $0$, not just the natural numbers greater than $0$. So even if you're right and the set $A$ is not bounded from above, this doesn't mean that $A =(0,\infty).\ $  Secondly, you've merely asserted "the set $A$ is not bounded above" without proof. Saying, "Set $A$ is not bounded from above because $n$ is a natural number" isn't convincing reasoning, and it seems you are more-or-less assuming that Theorem 1.20(a) is obviously true here: but you're not allowed to use the theorem you're trying to prove when trying to prove that theorem.

Comment: If you think that Set $A$ is not bounded above, you need to provide a convincing argument. And this is exactly what Rudin does with his proof: he provides a convincing logical argument that Set $A$ is not bounded above. He does this by assuming (a) is false, and then $y$ would be an upper bound of $A$ by definition. He then shows that an absurdity arises, and therefore, (a) is true (argument by contradiction). Note that it is clear that "the set $A$ is bounded above" is equivalent to saying" (a) is false". And saying "the set $A$ is not bounded above" is equivalent to saying "(a) is true".

Comment: However, it *isn't* immediately obvious whether or not $A$ is actually bounded above or not (this is more or less what we are trying to prove - and Rudin's prove that, in fact, $A$ is not bounded above).

Comment: Before saying A = (0, infinity) I did add a qualifier that x is varying and again " set A is not bdd above because n is natural no." was specific to when x is fixed. If you want to proof set A is not bdd above. first of all, It's obvious that it's true. I can't proof that obvious fact. you can check out "there is a hole in mathematics" by vertasium.

Comment: Is there a way to proof this thm without defining any set ?

Comment: The fact that you can’t come up with a proof for the Theorem neither means that a proof doesn’t exist, nor that Rudin’s theorem is wrong. It seems that you might have misunderstood the point of Veritasium’s video, as it has nothing whatsoever to do with this Theorem.

Comment: Start with an easier book than Rudin imo

Comment: By referring vertasium video. I just wanted to say how hard it is to proof obvious statement.

Comment: Well, Veritasium's video was about things more complicated than "proofs are hard". But yes, proofs often are hard to write and it's also hard to understand someone else's proof. These skills take time to get good at. Which is why I suggest something simpler than Rudin. Maybe go and find a book where you can study different types of proofs, like "How to prove it" [Cambridge].

Comment: Why do you think Rudin is hard for me ? Is it because I asked this question ? From my perspective it is the most obvious que we can ask after reading proof. After all this discussion your statement - Note that it is clear that " set A is bounded above" is equivalent to saying "(a) is false" is making complete sense. Maybe this is the right way to think. And writing proofs is not magic or only certain people can do it and rest can't. We all think like a human since we're human. I have checked that book yesterday when I was reading your others answer.

Comment: Rudin is hard for everyone who attempts it. And it's good that it's starting to make sense. Sometimes it takes me a long time to understand proofs also... the important thing is to take time away from the proof and come back to it later with a fresh mind. But it sounded like you didn't get that the form of the proof was an argument from contradiction, which it "obviously" is...

Comment: No, and I find it strange that you would ask for me to do such a favour when I don't know you in real life. I haven't been at University for 10 years. And like I say, this isn't the right website to ask for such help. You should find a website more suitable for this like a university forum, or better, phone the maths department of the university you are applying to and ask them any questions you would have regarding your application.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. So you know $A$ must contain an element larger than $y$.

The proof, presumably, is trying to prove that it doesn't have an upper bound, by contradiction.

Comment: This make sense. Here is my conclusion from your ans - thm 1.20(a) is trying to say, if we have a set A={nx..} if we choose a particular element of this set. Then, there exist an element (€ set A) which is greater than the chosen  element. We could continue this monotonous line of reasoning to conclude set A doesn't have a upper bound. For the moment, I'm assuming your explanation is correct and satisfactory. How did you come with this thought like someone told you ? or by ourself ?

Comment: By above reasoning, it is reasonable to say and prove y > nx ; y & nx are element of set A.

Comment: The fact that there's always another element in $A$ greater than any given element isn't enough to show there's no upper bound (For instance, $\{1-1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geq 1\}$ has this property.) The necessary argument is surely in the proof you are asking about.

Comment: Understood. It is obvious, nature of set A is not similar to given example.